# Backup SQL Server to Google Drive

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2014, azure-vm

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2014 on an Azure VM (Windows Server 2012 R2) with one database. Is it possible to configure an automatic backup to my Google Drive folder? Maybe a special tool or somethings else?

Comment: What's an automatic backup? Is it a backup created automatically by job/script at scheduled times or one that's done manually and uploaded automatically onto the Google drive? For achieving all of these you'll need some manual scripting.

Comment: this post got famous: http://dbareactions.com/post/143016494130/when-i-see-a-question-about-backing-up-sql-server :D

Comment: I'm using SQLBackupAndFTP. This tool creates backups according  to my schedule and sends them to my Google Drive. You can find more info here: https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/how-to-backup-sql-server-to-google-drive/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Download the [Google Drive](https://www.bing.com/search?q=google+drive+desktop&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN#) desktop application.
2. When backing up SQL Server, set the destination to the "My Drive" folder created by Google Drive (something like `C:\Users\<user>\Google Drive` by default)
3. Once a backup is placed in that folder, it will automatically start to sync to Google Drive.

Also worth nothing, as per Shawn Melton's comment:

You can adjust the folder location for the drive application, so it does not have to reside in a user folder. Any Administrator can actually remove a user profile and you just lost all your backups (locally at least).

Comment: But this solution has a huge flaw: you will not get informed if the upload is unsuccessful. Wouldn't it be better to have a batch script with a command line tool, like [gdrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) ?

Comment: @Twinkles There certainly could be a more complex and efficient approach to this - but based on the fact that GDrive is being used for backups, I chose to keep the scope small on the assumption that a complicated solution is not what the question/user required.

Comment: I get that. However, if a solution can lead to backups failing silently, the user better be aware of the risk.